# Problem in iterating list of self referencing entities (Spring Boot + Thymeleaf)

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm developing an e-commerce application and I have a Category class and an Item class among others. Category is self-referencing as it is supposed to handle subcategories as well. Now I'm trying to make a select element iterating through all categories, but my brain just cant figure out how to do this. It may be that my way of thinking about categories is all wrong and the whole logic needs to be re-evaluated.. comment are more than welcome on that level too!

Class Item:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class Item implements Serializable, Comparable<Item> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    
    private ItemType itemType;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category")
    private Category category;

        ... Unrelated object properties etc.
}
```

Class Category:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class Category extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentCategory")
    private Category parentCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCategory")
    private List<Category> subCategories = new ArrayList<>();

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Category(String name) {
        
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public Category(String name, Category parent) {
        
        this.name = name;
        
        this.parentCategory = parent;
    }

}
```

List of categories added to model:

```
model.addAttribute("categories", categoryRepository.findAll());
```

Thymeleaf:

```
<select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
    <option>All</option>
    <div th:each="category : ${categories}">
        <option class="optionGroup"  th:text="${category.name}" th:value="${category.id}"></option>
        <option  class="optionChild" th:each="subCategory : ${category.subCategories}"  th:text="${subCategory.name}" th:value="${subCategory.id}"></option>
    </div>
</select>
```

Shows up as:

[image: turns out like this:]

The idea offcourse is to show child categories under parent categories (Drink > Alcohol > Beer etc.)
Now, I'm not sure how to think about this. Maybe the fix lies in JPARepository queries. Maybe I shoul not use findAll() but something custom. Anyway I have to deal with that issue, when I want to find Items based on their category: how to include child categories to the results of a query?

Ps. I'm not using optgroup because I want also the parent categories to be choosable.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to xerx593 advice in getting the "main categorien" from the database as the starting point, I ended up with a solution with thymeleaf, that is not beautiful and has still some problems. But the iteration works like this at least somehow:
[A solution as a question :)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71708208/why-does-padding-not-work-with-option-elements-and-why-div-is-not-cool-as-a-chil)

Answer (score 1):

Simplest solution (in `CategoryRepository`):

```
// finds only parent categories
List<Category> findByParentCategoryIsNull();
```

or with a "custom naming" and `@Query`:

```
@Query("select c from Category c where c.parentCategory is null")
List<Category> findParents();
```

Comment: Thank you, this gets me started at least! Still, if I want to hang to my original idea, the Alcohol category for example, is a parent of Beer and a child of Drink.

Comment: welcome! :) ...then (when you say: "I'm developing an e-commerce application") lets think user/customer oriented: How many (total) categories are there? (how extensible/flexible are they)? How do the users would like to select it? (thinking of *many* categories, i would propose an "auto complete" or more "structure oriented" (then rather not with a `<select/>`))

Comment: The above <select> is used when searching for items. Other parameters of the form are such as product name, product number etc. and one should be able to for example  search by product name in certain categories. The idea atm. is that admin could create as many categories, subcategories, subsubcategories etc. as is needed for the types of items that are sold. Customers would then see the categories listed in a sidebar of the shop. The <select> element is only used when searchin for items.. I have to check into the autofill approach! Thanks again :)

Comment: By the way, what would be an example of a "structure oriented" approach?

Comment: When I said "structurered", I took a look at the (latest/current) product categories of (e.g.) Amazon & ebay, ..("web trader";) ...but they invested more than 1-man/day :))

Comment: autofill sounds cool for a "business app" (users are employees/not customers)! ..but to know it exactly, you'd have to "survey"/talk to an UX-guy

Comment: "structure" is also given by the relational (db) model (parent-child-sub... (the above query, would get you the root categories(hoepfully) with structure)), the question is: how do you want to represent (also/even with <select/>)?

Comment: I got the business side working with a type of autofill okay so far (<input  list="category"...> + <datalist id="category...> + <option>. This is also what I'm going to use at the customer-side search functionality. But the basic view in customer "shop" side is a constant side-panel with categories listed. Each parent category is a dropdown button (and a link). At the moment i have added to the Category class an Integer property "subCategoryLevel" witch I have a feeling that I could use when creating this list of  categories :D