# Why does padding not work with option-elements and why div is not cool as a child of a select-element?

Tags: html, css, thymeleaf

I'm trying to iterate an array of objects with arrays of objects with arrays etc. I'm pretty close to achieve what I'm trying to, but cant come up with any ideas on how to get to the goal.

I have a class that looks like this:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class Category extends AbstractPersistable<Long> {

    @NotNull
    private String name;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parentCategory")
    private Category parentCategory;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentCategory")
    private List<Category> subCategories = new ArrayList<>();

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category")
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
    
    public Category(String name) {
        
        this.name = name;
    }
    
    public Category(String name, Category parent) {
        
        this.name = name;
        
        this.parentCategory = parent;
    }
    
    public Integer categoryLevel;
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        
        return this.name;
    }

}
```

I'm sending a list of the "main" categories to thymeleaf thusly:

```
@Query("select c from Category c where c.parentCategory is null")
List<Category> findMainCategories();
----------------
model.addAttribute("mainCategories", categoryRepository.findMainCategories());
```

Now, I manage to access the subcategories and the sub-subcategories etc. with a monster code like this, but NetBeans is warning me of using a div tag as a child of a select-tag:

```
<div class="form-group mr-2">
    <label for="category">Category</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="category" name="category">
        <option>All</option>
        <div th:each="category : ${mainCategories}">
            <option class="optionGroup"  th:text="${category.name}" th:value="${category.id}"></option>
            <div th:each="subCategory1 : ${category.subCategories}">
                <option class="optionChild1" th:text="${subCategory1.name}" th:value="${subCategory1.id}"></option>
                <div th:each="subCategory2 : ${subCategory1.subCategories}">
                    <option class="optionChild2" th:text="${subCategory2.name}" th:value="${subCategory2.id}"></option>
                    <div th:each="subCategory3 : ${subCategory2.subCategories}">
                        <option class="optionChild3" th:text="${subCategory3.name}" th:value="${subCategory3.id}"></option>
                        <div th:each="subCategory4 : ${subCategory3.subCategories}">
                            <option class="optionChild4" th:text="${subCategory4.name}" th:value="${subCategory4.id}"></option>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </select>
</div>
```

The css classes seen above (otionGroup and optionChild1..2...3..4) works in formatting the font, but not in adding the padding. The css looks like this:

```
.optionGroup {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}

.optionChild1 {
    padding-left: 15px !important;
}

.optionChild2 {
    padding-left:  30px !important;
}

.optionChild3 {
    padding-left:  45px !important;
}

.optionChild4 {
    padding-left:  60px !important;
}
```

The categories in the database are:

[image: categories]

And the result in the browser looks like this:

[image: Screen shot of the Select-element]

So mainly my problem is the padding because now it just does not group the right things and this is a horrible user-interface. Also, if there is a "right" way to iterate through this kind of a dataset, I would be really glad to learn!

Ps. I'm not using optgroup-tag because I need the "groups" too to be selectable.

Thank You in advance!

Comment: your html is invalid - you can't just shove a div in a select and expect it to work properly just because you don't want to use optgroup

Comment: I understand that it is not kosher. But the iteration works. Why does the css padding not work?